# Which EncodeFor on data- attributes with URLs

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, custom-data-attribute, coldfusion-2018

I am trying put a URL into a `data-` attribute. In particular

```
<tr data-href="/page.cfm?Id=#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(ID)#">
   ...
```

OR perhaps it should be

```
<tr data-href="/page.cfm?Id=#EncodeForURL(ID)#">
   ...
```

Note that ID can have special characters

**Edit:**

Much later I am going to

```
$("tr").click(function() { window.location = $(this).data("href"); });
```

Comment: My guess would be to use `#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(ID)#` but it's just that... a guess.

Comment: I assume it will be related to the use. Suppose you going to render the URL on the HTML, then i will go for `#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(ID)#`. In the other case, if you going to use it on a POST/GET i will go for `#EncodeForURL(ID)#`

Comment: @D.Smania edited to add info that addresses concern

Comment: In my mind what you are going to do with the data later is irrelevant. Any cross-site scripting attack will happen when the browser works to render the HTML attribute, not later when you try to run JavaScript code against it. Now obviously you will need to handle the encoding later when you do try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us analyze some scenarios:

## Not encoding at all

```
<!--- our "tricky" ID --->
<cfset ID = '"><script>alert("my evil script");</script><div foo="'>
<!--- we are closing the data-href attribute, injecting our JS and start a new tag to complete the remaining tag --->

<cfoutput>

    <div data-href="page.cfm?Id=#ID#"></div>
    <!--- [data-href] is printed as: page.cfm?Id="><script>alert("my evil script");</script><div foo=" --->

</cfoutput>
```

### Result

An alert dialog apppears with "my evil script".

### Conclusion

**Never leave user input unencoded!** (You already knew that.)

---

## Encoding the query string for output as HTML

Note: You should always encode the full value of an HTML attribute, not just parts of it.

```
<!--- our "tricky" ID --->
<cfset ID = "&a=b?c">
<!--- we are having some reserved characters here that will confuse the browser's query string parser --->

<cfoutput>

    <div data-href="#encodeForHtmlAttribute("page.cfm?Id=#ID#")#"></div>
    <!--- [data-href] is printed as: page.cfm&#x3f;Id&#x3d;&amp;a&#x3d;b&#x3f;c --->

    <script>

        var attr = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('data-href');

        console.log(attr); <!--- page.cfm?Id=&a=b?c --->

        <cfif structIsEmpty(URL)> <!--- test related: to prevent infinite redirection --->
            location.href = attr;
        </cfif>

    </script>

</cfoutput>

<cfdump var="#URL#">
```

### Result

When requesting `page.cfm`, we will be redirected to `page.cfm?Id=&a=b?c`, the plain value of the `data-href` attribute. However, the scope dump of `URL` will present us the key-value-pairs:

```
Id: [empty string]
 a: b?c
```

Which is to be expected, because the browser's query string parser could not distinguish between literal meaning and technical purpose of the characters. [I recently answered this here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729271/which-encodefor-should-be-used-for-location/52730896#52730896)

### Conclusion

Encoding the output isn't sufficient when having multiple contexts (here: HTML & URL/QueryString).

---

## Encoding the query string as URL

```
<!--- our "tricky" ID --->
 <cfset ID = 'a&b="><script>alert("my evil script");</script><div foo="'>
 <!--- we are mixing in both contexts now --->

 <cfoutput>

     <div data-href="page.cfm?Id=#encodeForUrl(ID)#"></div>
     <!--- [data-href] is printed as: page.cfm?Id=a%26b%3D%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22my+evil+script%22%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cdiv+foo%3D%22 --->

     <script>

         var attr = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('data-href');

         console.log(attr); <!--- page.cfm?Id=a%26b%3D%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22my+evil+script%22%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cdiv+foo%3D%22 --->

         <cfif structIsEmpty(URL)> <!--- test related: to prevent infinite redirection --->
             location.href = attr;
         </cfif>

     </script>

 </cfoutput>

 <cfdump var="#URL#">
```

### Result

When requesting `page.cfm`, we will be redirected to `page.cfm?Id=a%26b%3D%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22my+evil+script%22%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cdiv+foo%3D%22`, the plain value of the `data-href` attribute. The scope dump of `URL` will present us the key-value-pair:

```
Id: a&b="><script>alert("my evil script");</script><div foo="
```

This time, the browser's query string parser could distinguish between literal meaning and technical purpose of the characters. But what about the HTML context here? Well, the percent-encoding done by `encodeForUrl()` doesn't conflict with HTML's reserved characters, because `%` has no technical purpose in HTML and doesn't break anything.

### Conclusion

Theoretically we are done here. There is no need to HTML-encode the URL-encoded value since there is no overlap of the two encodings.

---

## Encoding the query string as URL - AND - for output as HTML

```
<!--- our "tricky" ID --->
 <cfset ID = 'a&b="><script>alert("my evil script");</script><div foo="'>
<!--- we are mixing in both contexts again --->

<cfoutput>

    <div data-href="#encodeForHtmlAttribute("page.cfm?Id=#encodeForUrl(ID)#")#"></div>
    <!--- [data-href] is printed as: page.cfm&#x3f;Id&#x3d;a&#x25;26b&#x25;3D&#x25;22&#x25;3E&#x25;3Cscript&#x25;3Ealert&#x25;28&#x25;22my&#x2b;evil&#x2b;script&#x25;22&#x25;29&#x25;3B&#x25;3C&#x25;2Fscript&#x25;3E&#x25;3Cdiv&#x2b;foo&#x25;3D&#x25;22 --->

    <script>

        var attr = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('data-href');

        console.log(attr); <!--- page.cfm?Id=a%26b%3D%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22my+evil+script%22%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cdiv+foo%3D%22 --->

        <cfif structIsEmpty(URL)> <!--- test related: to prevent infinite redirection --->
            location.href = attr;
        </cfif>

    </script>

</cfoutput>

<cfdump var="#URL#">
```

### Result

When requesting `page.cfm`, we will be redirected to `page.cfm?Id=a%26b%3D%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22my+evil+script%22%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cdiv+foo%3D%22`, the plain value of the `data-href` attribute. The scope dump of `URL` will present us the key-value-pair:

```
Id: a&b="><script>alert("my evil script");</script><div foo="
```

Nothing seems to have changed, right? Not exactly. This is what our `data-href` now looks like in the final HTML output:
`page.cfm&#x3f;Id&#x3d;a&#x25;26b&#x25;3D&#x25;22&#x25;3E&#x25;3Cscript&#x25;3Ealert&#x25;28&#x25;22my&#x2b;evil&#x2b;script&#x25;22&#x25;29&#x25;3B&#x25;3C&#x25;2Fscript&#x25;3E&#x25;3Cdiv&#x2b;foo&#x25;3D&#x25;22`
As you can see, the percent-encoding is now additionally encoded for HTML (the `%` was encoded to its hex respresentation `&#x25;`).

### Conclusion

The value is now safe for both contexts.

---

There are more encodings that could mix in (think of `encodeForJavaScript()`), but you get the idea. It's always about which characters in a value require encoding to not be misinterpreted for their technical purpose. This can end up as wild as having 3 to 4 nested encodings. But then again: Usually those encodings do not conflict with each other, so it is not necessarily required to have them encoded for all their contexts.